# How to calculate the of average/mean geographical position in MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregate

I would like to create a query to calculate the average geographical position of all tree species in MongoDb.My code is here:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from utils import get_my_password, get_my_username
from pprint import pprint


client = MongoClient(
    host='127.0.0.1',
    port=27017,
    username=get_my_username(),
    password=get_my_password(),
    authSource='admin'
)

db = client['paris']
col = db['trees']

pprint(col.find_one())

{'_id': ObjectId('5f3276d8c22f704983b3f681'),
 'adresse': 'JARDIN DU CHAMP DE MARS / C04',
 'arrondissement': 'PARIS 7E ARRDT',
 'circonferenceencm': 115.0,
 'domanialite': 'Jardin',
 'espece': 'hippocastanum',
 'genre': 'Aesculus',
 'geo_point_2d': [48.8561906007, 2.29586827747],
 'hauteurenm': 11.0,
 'idbase': 107224.0,
 'idemplacement': 'P0040937',
 'libellefrancais': 'Marronnier',
 'remarquable': '0',
 'stadedeveloppement': 'A',
 'typeemplacement': 'Arbre'}

I tryed to do it with next lines:

cursor = col.aggregate([
    {'$match': {first: $arrayElemAt: [ "$geo_point_2d", 0 ]},
               {last: $arrayElemAt: [ "$geo_point_2d", 1 ]}},
    {'$group': {'_id': '$espece', 'GeoMeanTreeSpieces': {'$avg': 1}}},
    {'$project': {'_id': 0, 'espece': '$_id', 'GeoMeanTreeSpieces': '$GeoMeanTreeSpieces'}}
])

print(list(cursor))
```

It doesn't work. I need more and more practices. I got this error:

```
File "<ipython-input-9-2a108c75c8c4>", line 20
    {'$match': {first: $arrayElemAt: [ "$geo_point_2d", 0 ]},
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could you help me please to find a solution please?
Best regards

Comment: Please provide some sample documents

Comment: Sorry, I am confused, I don't have any other documents, it is exercise for training with information I have. Maybe I understand wrong your demande. I can show this: {'_id': ObjectId('5f3276d8c22f704983b3f681'),
  'espece': 'hippocastanum',
 'genre': 'Aesculus',
 'geo_point_2d': [48.8561906007, 2.29586827747],
 'hauteurenm': 11.0,
 'idbase': 107224.0,
 'idemplacement': 'P0040937',...
 'typeemplacement': 'Arbre'}

Comment: In this case, what are your expected results from the query? Please provide the query expected output

Comment: AA, understand, sorry. I would like to have like this: [{'espece': 'hippocastanum', 'GeoMeanTreeSpieces': ((geo_point[0]+geo_point[1])/2)},...]

Comment: What do you mean by "average geographical position"? In case you need to be more accurate, have a look at [Turf.js](https://turfjs.org/docs/#center) (center, centerOfMass, centroid). I guess, you will find similar library also for Python. For only two points which are close to each other, it should be OK, however when you have  more points you may run into problems, because Lat/Lon are not Cartesian coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly (this is not the actual GeoMeanTreeSpieces, the name is confusing):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      GeoMeanTreeSpieces: {
        $divide: [
          {$add: [{$first: "$geo_point_2d"}, {$last: "$geo_point_2d"}]},
          2
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/v5XbgH2dwCB)

Answer (score 0):

I found out the SOLUTION of this task:

```
pipeline=[
      {"$group": {"_id": "$espece", 
                  "x_moyen": {"$avg": {"$arrayElemAt":["$geo_point_2d",0]}},
                  "y_moyen": {"$avg": {"$arrayElemAt":["$geo_point_2d",1]}},
                 }},                   
]

pprint(list(col.aggregate(pipeline=pipeline))[:10])
```

And the answer:

```
[{'_id': 'rufa', 'x_moyen': 48.8370548843, 'y_moyen': 2.44577495275},
 {'_id': 'antarctica',
  'x_moyen': 48.887011929275,
  'y_moyen': 2.3707275018700003},
 {'_id': 'vulgaris',
  x_moyen': 48.82593008238334,
  'y_moyen': 2.4511533611338887},
 {'_id': 'venustula', 'x_moyen': 48.820849268, 'y_moyen': 2.45398620992},
 {'_id': 'monophylla',
  'x_moyen': 48.821262685099995,
  'y_moyen': 2.455444424045},
 {'_id': 'verticillata',
  'x_moyen': 48.82065495999999,
  'y_moyen': 2.45680436618},
 {'_id': 'x media', 'x_moyen': 48.8672036959, 'y_moyen': 2.3482812026358535},
 {'_id': 'orientalis',
  'x_moyen': 48.83334073763992,
  'y_moyen': 2.362370810808307},
 {'_id': 'typhina',
  'x_moyen': 48.872847743710864,
  'y_moyen': 2.398939027817174},
 {'_id': 'incisa', 'x_moyen': 48.85942981336666, 'y_moyen': 2.2922408362633333}]
```

I was not clear when I ask about it. Thank you for help.
Best regards